# Fancybox popup is moving to top

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-3

I am using fancy box to show contact form 7 in popup on clicking of a link. its working fine but its being displayed on very top center of the page. Here you can see the button "Book now" on clicking it opens a popup. Book Now 
https://lacalarentals.com/2018/08/05/2-bedroom-luxury-garden-apartment/

```
var ready; ready = function() { jQuery(".popup2").fancybox({ 'content': jQuery('#showcontactform') }); }; jQuery(document).ready(ready); jQuery(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Please let me know how to fix?

Comment: I am so sorry. Please check it now.

Comment: I could not find "Book now" button, but it looks like you are using v1 (unsupported and somehow broken on your site), I strongly suggest to upgrade to the latest version.